# Error:(10, 6) Error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have some problems with that ScrollView."element ScrollView must be declared and i dont know what i can do with that markup somebody can help me ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_color" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close_activity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top|end"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/closebutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/close" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/close_activity" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use self-closing tags with non-empty elements.**

Replace

```
android:scrollbars="none" />
```

with

```
android:scrollbars="none">
```

and

```
android:background="@color/background_color"/>
```

with

```
android:background="@color/background_color">
```

otherwise your XML won't be well-formed.

Comment: just  </ScrollView> highlighted in red and not working ;/

Comment: @kubade220: If you make the two changes listed in my answer to your posted XML, then it will be well-formed.  If you're still having problems, you'll have to be clear on what exactly what your new XML looks like (edit your question and add it) if you want further help.